# Three.js renders unprocessed png image for texture

Tags: three.js, glsl

With three.js, I am trying to create the scene where a plane becomes transparent as the camera moves away from it.

And I textured the plane object with the round map tile which is edited from the square image below.

[image]

[image]

When I load the round image through ShaderMaterial the texture appears square like the original image.

The weird thing is it is rendered as intended when the image is loaded onto regular mesh material.

Could you tell me why three.js behaves this way? Also, how might I render round tile using shader while keeping its functionality to fade based on distance?

**the full code is available here: https://codesandbox.io/s/tile-with-shader-7kw5v?file=/src/index.js**

[image]

Comment: if you comment out the line `textureCol.a = 1.0 - rad / u_rad;` in the `frag.glsl`, you'll see rounded map.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but it won't have the desired effect if I comment that line out. Plus I'd like to know why and how three.js reverts the png file to its original

Comment: It doesn't. Somehow you compute `a`-channel in shaders the way that it's always greater than 0 (or even greater than 1) for the pixels of the plane.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an option, that takes in count only `x` and `z` coords of the plane and the camera.

`vertex.glsl`:

```c
varying vec4 vPosition;
varying vec2 vUv;

void main() {
  vPosition = modelMatrix * vec4(position, 1.);
  vUv = uv;
  gl_Position = projectionMatrix * viewMatrix * vPosition;
}
```

`frag.glsl`:

```c
uniform vec3 u_color;
uniform vec3 u_camera;
uniform vec3 u_plane;
uniform float u_rad;
uniform sampler2D u_texture;

varying vec4 vPosition;
varying vec2 vUv;

void main() {
  vec4 textureCol = texture2D(u_texture, vUv);
  float rad = distance(vPosition.xz, u_camera.xz); // xz-plane
  textureCol.a = 1.0 - step(1., rad / u_rad);

  gl_FragColor = textureCol;
}
```

and `u_rad` uniform is
`u_rad: { value: 50 },`